# How to Enable side scrolling on Lenovo 3000 G530

Tags: lenovo-laptop, scrolling

I have a lenovo 3000 G530. How do I enable side scrolling(scrolling pages with one finger at the side) on the touchpad?

Comment: Did you try to install/reinstall touchpad driver? On my laptops side scrolling works only when touchpad driver  installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the directions from Lenovo Tech Support: 
 (Their site seems to be down, so this is a link to google cache.) 
 http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:iY94z_hTTBUJ:consumersupport.lenovo.com/ot/en/HintsandTips/Hints_Count.aspx